# How to make `clamdscan` exclude folders and only log `--infected`？

Tags: clamav

My server is centos 7.4, with clamav 0.101.1-1.el7.
When I run `clamscan -r --infected  --exclude-dir="^/sys" /` through terminal,  I always wait more than 6 hours to get output.
And  if I close terminal, `clamscan` will stop.

Then I want to use `clamdscan` to scan in background.
My question are:
1.How to `--exclude-dir="^/sys" /` with `clamdscan`?
2.How to make `clamdscan` only log `--infected`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`clamdscan` does not have as many options available via the command line as `clamscan`
`clamdscan` reads most of its options from it's config file `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf`
You can add multiple `ExcludePath` options in `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` file.
These are in RegEx:

```
ExcludePath ^/dev/
ExcludePath ^/proc/
ExcludePath ^/sys/
```

Then you can run it with:

```
clamdscan --multiscan --fdpass --quiet /
```

`--multiscan` will speed up the processing because it uses multiple threads.
`--fdpass` will allow you to scan files as the clamd user that the clamav-daemon.service runs as.
`--quiet` should suppress all output except infected files. At least that's what it seems to do on my system but that isn't how it is described in the documentation.

If you want to save to file you can just redirect the output `clamdscan <options> > /save/file.txt`
Or save it to file with the `--log=FILE` option.

Put you command in a cron job an you are done.
If you are scripting something I would suggest checking the exit codes for `clamdscan` and then having your script email you when it detects a virus:

> 0 : No virus found.
>   1 : Virus(es) found.
>   2 : An error occurred.

`clamdscan` documentation: https://linux.die.net/man/1/clamdscan
`clamd.conf` documentation: https://linux.die.net/man/5/clamd.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to create a cron.daily script that will email only if infected>0.

`echo -e '#!/bin/bash \nclamlog=/var/log/clamav/clamav.log; rm -f $clamlog; touch $clamlog \nnice -n5 clamscan -ri / --exclude-dir=/proc --exclude-dir=/sys --exclude-dir=/dev --exclude-dir=/media --exclude-dir=/mnt -l clamav.log \nMALWARE=$(tail "clamav.log"|grep Infected|cut -d" " -f3) && if [ "$MALWARE" -ne "0" ]; then mail -s "Malware Found" $EMAIL <<< $(cat clamav.log); fi && rm -f clamav.log' > "/etc/cron.daily/clamscan_daily" && chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/clamscan_daily`

`echo -e 'service clamav-freshclam stop && freshclam && service clamav-freshclam start' >> "/etc/cron.daily/clamscan_daily"`

```
#!/bin/bash
clamlog=/var/log/clamav/clamav.log; rm -f $clamlog; touch $clamlog
nice -n5 clamscan -ri / --excluded-dir=/proc --exclude-dir=/sys --exclude-dir=/dev 
    --exclude-dir=/media --exclude-dir=/mnt -l $clamlog 
MALWARE=$(tail "$clamlog"|grep Infected|cut -d" " -f3) && if [ "$MALWARE" -ne "0" ]; 
    then mail -s "Malware Found $(hostname -i; uname -a)" $(cat ~/.env/EMAIL) <<< 
    $(cat $clamlog); fi
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

clamscan --recursive --infected --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev /path

Comment: The question was specifically about `clamdscan` and not about `clamscan`.

Comment: it needs to be `--exclude-dir` not `--exclude`